# Why is this regex not working with re.search?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to extract canadian postal code from text using regular expression.

I have tried this regex from [link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch04s15.html)

```
pattern = "^(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z].[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$"

temp = 'Portland Street,  Burnaby, BC V5E 1A1'
re.search(pattern, temp) # returns None
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The dot you have copied should be a regular period, not that larger symbol.

Comment: @RoboMop Tried that, it didn't work as well.

Comment: What do you want the output to be? "V5E 1A1"?

Comment: @Nadine I just want to extract the Canadian postal codes from addresses? I have a huge dataset and I want to extract only all the canadian postal codes found.

Comment: that reg ex pattern only validates the postal code part, it does not extract it.  it will fail if you have adress in front of the postal code.

Comment: @ChristianSloper How can I modify the regex and extract so that it can work even if address if found at front of postal code? I am not well-versed in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re findall may be quite useful too, it will compile all matches into a list for you:

```
import re

pattern = "(?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z].[0-9][A-Z][0-9](?<!\.)"

temp = 'John Oliver 7111 Portland Street,  Burnaby, BC V5E 1A1  Phone: 212-456-0781  Email: johnny@gmail.com'
r = re.findall(pattern, temp)
print(r)
```

> Result

```
['V5E 1A1']
```

Comment: It is not working for strings like `John Oliver 7111 Portland Street,  Burnaby, BC V5E 1A1  Phone: 212-456-0781  Email: johnny@gmail.com`?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I added a negative look behind

Answer (score 1):

Not Canadian and not well versed in postal codes, so no guarantees :-)

```
import re

pattern = "^(.*)((?!.*[DFIOQU])[A-VXY][0-9][A-Z].[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$)"

temp = 'Portland Street,  Burnaby, BC V5E 1A1'
r = re.search(pattern, temp)
print(r.groups())
```

this yields:

```
('Portland Street,  Burnaby, BC ', 'V5E 1A1')
```

(post code in second group)

Note that this probably goes to shit if there is no postal code, in that case you will only have one group though, so you can filter those.

Comment: Actually it is not working for strings like `John Oliver 7111 Portland Street,  Burnaby, BC V5E 1A1  Phone: 212-456-0781  Email: johnny@gmail.com`?

Comment: yeah, this particular regex requires the post code to be at the end.